# Java to JavaScript with NodeJS convertion

Tags: java, javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I have lots of code written on Java that actively interacts with file system. I have rewritten part of this code to NodeJS (on CoffeeScript), and it works fine. But all this I did manually. The question is: are there any tools that can perform such a conversion?

I'm ready to use MPS for writing my own generator but this is not the easiest way.

So, any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think there is such a tool yet.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such generic tool, since duplicating all existing Java API into Node.js equivalents would be prohibitively expensive for very little gain.

You could always shell out to a Java process from Node.js.

Answer (score 0):

[GWT](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/) would be the closes way of converting Java to javascript. unfortunately there isn't a way to to convert it to NodeJS